# Tensorflow better model loading

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am traing to load my model without my database, but I have to use Standard Scale split. This is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
dataset = pd.read_csv('database.csv') #reading database
x = dataset.drop(columns=['good/bad']).values
y = dataset['good/bad'].values
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2)
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(x_train)
x_train = scaler.transform(x_train)

model = load_model("model.h5")

#Now I want to predict my data
out = scaler.transform([my_data])
prediction = model.predict(out)
pred = prediction[0][0]
```

Can I predict my data without loading my dataset?

Comment: what do you want to use for prediction ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, firstly you need to create a model. For the research models and techniques, most machine learning or deep learning practitioners use these steps:

- Data preprocess
- Create Model
- Save model
- Load model
- Make Prediction

More details have been already cleared in [Tensorflow official Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load)